# How do i calculate percentage out of sum in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage, with-statement

Ive got this simple table

| browser | pageviews |
| --- | --- |
| safari | 7.1875 |
| ie | 1.935 |
| firefix | 1.3445 |
| safari | 2.03 |

Im trying to calculate the percentage of the page views out of the total (in millions) for each browser.

```
with total as
( select sum(pageviews) as total
from pageviews )
select browser,
pageviews / total.total as share
from pageviews,
total
```

but im receiving this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'total as ( select sum(pageviews) as total

Any suggestion on how to calculate the percentage?
Thanks!

Comment: And what happened when you did that?

Comment: *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'total as ( select sum(pageviews) as total*  Your MySQL version is 5.x, and it does not support CTE. Upgrade.

Comment: @Akina It might be an idea to sit back and let the OP respond. Your comment is incorrect, and unhelpful.

Comment: The error you are getting seems to indicate that WITH is not supported in your version of MySQL, what version of MySQL are you using? WITH was introduced in version 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
select browser, 
       pageview,
       pageview / SUM(pageview) OVER () as share
from pageviews
```

For MySQL 5.x use

```
select browser,
       pageview,
       pageview / total.total as share
from pageviews
CROSS JOIN ( select sum(pageview) as total
             from pageviews ) total
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6c188ab43ec7a81495630bcc266f46bd

Comment: You are making the question more difficult than it is. the OP made an error in his field name, and you are 'silently' ignoring that error, and bloating it with the true! statement that you cannot do `WITH` in older version of MySQL.

Comment: @Luuk No. See error message in the question and my comment for it. *OP made an error in his field name* I don't know where is a typo - OP must fix it.

Comment: OK, but you answer is not about this problem, it is about a problem which does not exist (yet).   (BTW, the downvote on your 'answer' is not mine..)

Comment: *but you answer is not about this problem* Do you think that "Your version is ancient" must be written as separate answer? Really? I assume this as a typo (and more precisely like "OP have not read the documentation").

Comment: Obviously the OP's MySql version is prior to 8.0+, so I don't understand the downvote here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older version of MySQL then:

QUery:

> ```
> select browser,
> pageviews / total.total as share
> from pageviews,
> ( select sum(pageviews) as total
> from pageviews )total
> ```

Output:

> | browser | share |
> | --- | --- |
> | safari | 0.575138039579793 |
> | ie | 0.15483715807683296 |
> | firefix | 0.10758581745403162 |
> | safari | 0.1624389848893424 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=3ff83359a70cce3125bf574dc3e5365b)*

If you are using MySQL 8 then you can use window function:

```
select browser, pageviews / sum(pageviews)over(partition by (select 1)) as share from pageviews
```

**DB-Fiddle Link:**

> ```
> create table pageviews (browser varchar(20),pageviews float);
> insert into  pageviews values('safari',7.1875);
> insert into  pageviews values('ie',1.935);
> insert into  pageviews values('firefix',1.3445);
> insert into  pageviews values('safari',2.03);
> ```

> ```
> with total as
> ( select sum(pageviews) as total
> from pageviews )
> select browser,
> pageviews / total.total as share
> from pageviews,
> total
> ```

> | browser | share |
> | --- | --- |
> | safari | 0.575138039579793 |
> | ie | 0.15483715807683296 |
> | firefix | 0.10758581745403162 |
> | safari | 0.1624389848893424 |

> ```
> select browser, pageviews / sum(pageviews)over(partition by (select 1)) as share from pageviews
> ```

> | browser | share |
> | --- | --- |
> | safari | 0.575138039579793 |
> | ie | 0.15483715807683296 |
> | firefix | 0.10758581745403162 |
> | safari | 0.1624389848893424 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6d004054fc091875c80a001676fab15)*

*emphasized text*

Comment: Those are same in the query presented in the question. that's why it happened I think.

Comment: @Alon Kri if any of the answer helped you to solve the problem please accept that by clicking green check.

Comment: As discussed elsewhere, it's obvious that the OP is using an older version of MySQL.

Comment: I have added answer for older version of MySQL.

Comment: The OP is using a version of MySQL prior to 8.

Comment: That's why I have added a section in my answer which will work even in 5.5. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Why not put that bit at the top?

Comment: You are right again. I have changed order of query in my answer. You are a blessing.

Answer (score -1):

Change you query to use correct field names (You use `pageviews` as column name, but the name of this column is `pageview` ?):

```
with total as
( select sum(pageview) as total
from pageviews )
select browser,
pageview / total.total as share
from pageviews,
total
```